# failed install ubuntu gnome 16.04 when choose something else

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, system-installation

I want install ubuntu gnome 16.04/16.04.1 alongside win 10, but everytime I choose something else option, the installer program disappear but the installer icon still on top taskbar, also cannot quit.

I make the boot usb with the rufus 2.11, and can install ubuntu gnome 14.04,ubuntu mate 16.04 ,ubuntu 16.04 successfully. also tried the UUI usb, also not work! so it may not a rufus bug!

there is a very big  logo  `acer` screen before I seen  the black screen with choices of `Try ubuntu without installing` and `Install Ubuntu`

also, I choose `GO back` when `Force UEFI installation`prompt dialog popup, because it works on other ubuntu version.

Can anyone help, thanks!

my hardware is acer aspire 4752G with NVIDA Geforec 540M

Comment: Rufus is worst use : [UUI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Comment: @minigeek Please expand your comment about Rufus. I am interested in knowing if it ever happens with Rufus that the Ubuntu installer starts normally and then quits as soon as you select an option. If it did, that would be a bug

Comment: When you boot to the live media is it initially a black screen with choices of `Try ubuntu without installing` and `Install Ubuntu`.  Do you see this choice before you seen any `GUI`?

Comment: @karel yes i have seen this happened when usb is made bootable with rufus(yesterday only when my frnd did it for fresh install). that's why i recommend people using uui..this is not first time this has happened...might be a bug as u say

Comment: @L.D.James  there is a very big  logo  `acer` screen before I seen  the black screen with choices of `Try ubuntu without installing` and `Install Ubuntu `,  or maybe I forgot, WHEN I install ubuntu, it is sure there is a logo flash very fast. I add some info in question description hope  that can help solve this. thank you

Comment: On the `Black Screen` with choices hi `e` on the `Try Ubuntu without installing`.  Then replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.  Then hit `F10` to reboot.

Comment: With the limited lines of the comment I left out a part.  The process I explained will take you to the Desktop.  From there run the "Install Ubuntu" from the Desktop by clicking on the `Install Ubuntu` icon.  When it prompts you to connect to network (for quickness) don't connect.  Also don't place a check mark for `Install third-part software`.  All that can easily be done after the Install.  As far as your install medium, it's unlikely that's a problem.

Comment: @L.D.James, after replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`, it WORKS !  pay my respects to you！ thank you, I am a rookie in linux world and so happy to find out that the forum is amazing!

Comment: Glad it worked!  The answer shows how to add the skipped `Install third-party software`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are booting in `UEFI` mode.  On the black screen before the GUI you'll have choices.  Hit `e` on the `Try Ubuntu without installing`.

Use the navigate with the arrow keys and replace `quiet splach` with `nomodeset`.  Then hit `F10` to boot.

When you get to the Desktop, click on the `Install Ubuntu` icon.

When you get to choices of `Connect to Network` and `Install third-party software` skip those choices to make install go quicker.  You can easily add those items after the install.

After following the `GUI` install prompt, reboot and you should be all set.

You can get to the Canonical Partners option after the install by clicking on the Gear Icon at the top left of the Screen and going into `System Settings`.  Click on Software & Updates.  Place a check mark in `Canonical Partners`.