# Ubuntu stuck on boot

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I have an ASUS laptop, it has an Intel i3 and I'm pretty sure the motherboard is UEFI. Previously I had Tumbleweed installed on it, and I wanted to switch to Ubuntu.

I inserted a USB in my computer (didn't mount it) and used:

```
dd bs=2M if=/path/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress && sync
```

To copy it to the USB. When I inserted it into my laptop and used the BIOS to boot from the USB, I got a black screen with "Ubuntu" and an infinite loading message.

I'm quite unsure why, I had previously used the same USB stick to install SUSE and Arch and I'm quite sure it's been wiped before `dd` (though I'm not sure that even matters).

Comment: When you first boot to the USB stick, does it pause on a black screen with boot options, giving you a choice before all the scrolling lines you describe?

Comment: Yes, I picked the obvious big one "Install Ubuntu" at first but now I picked something around the lines of "check disk integrity" and it seems to be all the same. Also it seems to be stuck a "assuming device cach: writting trough"

Comment: Follow these steps: [failed install ubuntu gnome 16.04 when choose something else](http://askubuntu.com/questions/831798/failed-install-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-when-choose-something-else/831958#831958)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "booting in UEFI mode" means in this case. I chose "boot from UEFI flash usb" or some such, tbh I'm quite confused on the whole issue of UEFI vs BIOS. I'll try doing a bit more googling about it. Meanwhile try ubuntu without installing is blocked at the exact same "assuming drive cache:... " step.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the link?  You say you're not sure what UEFI means, but you also said you chooses the correct option.  You've gotten everything right so far.  Where in the steps are you actually getting stuck?  What is the last step for the link you did?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46168/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-george-h).

Comment: I had issues booting uefi to Ubuntu server. I had to in the uefi menu choose to boot to Legacy only. This was on a gigabyte desktop board not a laptop. Try this and see if it gives you different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved VIA `Chat` in the comments.  The steps were:

```
1) Boot to live disk
2) Select Try Ubuntu without installiing
3) Hit e to edit the grub commandline
4) Replace "quiet splash" with "nomodeset"
5) Hit F10
```